# jquery progress bar not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I have a for loop that I need to loop through and create progress bars with jquery.
For some reason, the progress bars just show up empty, with no shaded area and I can't seem to figure out why this could be.  I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenmandy/npo3srs2/2/) to show what I'm currently dealing with.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <table class="table" border=1>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td><strong>ProgressBars:</strong>

        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="progress"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  var taskDiv = '<div><table border=1 class="table table-condensed">';
  var progress = 47;

  taskDiv += ('<tr><td colspan="3"><div id="progressContainer' + i + '" class="progressContainer"><div id="progressbar' + i + '" class="progressbar"></div></div></td></tr>');

  setProgress(progress, i);

  taskDiv += ('</table></div>');
  $(taskDiv).appendTo('#progress');
}

function setProgress(progress, uid) {
  var progressBarWidth = $("#progressContainer" + uid).width() * (progress / 100);
  $("#progressbar" + uid).width(progressBarWidth).html(progress + "% ");
}
```

CSS:

```
/* Progress bar */

.progressbar {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  height: 25px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.progressContainer {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 10px 5px 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: `$(taskDiv).appendTo($('#progress'))` ?

Comment: Something to note is that 'progressBarWidth' is always set to 0 in your code

Comment: @wscourge didn't do the trick wrapping in parens.  :(

Comment: My mistake, I mixed up fnctions

Comment: @JDun I added in 'console.log(progressBarWidth);' to check, and it was 0 everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the progress AFTER you append the HTML of the progress bars. 
Like this:

```
taskDiv += ('</table></div>');
$(taskDiv).appendTo('#progress');

setProgress(progress, i);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnfgk8uk/)

Otherwise, when you call the setProgress function there's no `$("#progressbar")` elements and that function does nothing.

Comment: Hallelujah for you!  Thank you so much for your answer.  I didn't even realize I needed to change the level of progress after adding the html to the div.  Makes sense to me now!  :)